# sum of recursive tree using Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a tree structure that looks like this:

```
                                     root
                       A                               B
              A1           A2                     B1        B2
          A1.1  A1.2      A2.1                   B1.1
```

the table looks something like this:

```
id | name |value | parent_id
1    root   null    null
2    A      null    1
3    B      null    1    
4    A1     null    2
5    A1.1   2       4
6    A1.2   3       4
.........................
```

the non leaf nodes must contain the sum of their children leaf nodes.

how can i achieve this with a fast Postgres query

Comment: If there only one root node you can just use `sum` of value

Comment: @D-Shih yes but i want to retrieve the sum of all non leaf nodes and store their values inside the value column

Comment: I wrote an answer for you in below hope that help

Comment: your answer calculates the value of root but leaves the values of both A and B (which are both parent nodes to their children ) with value NULL. i want all the nodes to be populated with the sum of their children

Comment: Could you provide your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: @D-Shih  basically what i want is the tree to have all of its parent nodes ( not just the root node ) contain the sum of their respective children as their value. what your code does is calculate the sum of the entire tree but the values of the parent nodes (A and B) still contain null

Comment: I had edited my answer you can try that but you don't provide expected result I am not sure is that your expect

Answer (score 0):

As I comment, If there is only one root node in your table you can just use `sum` of value

```
SELECT SUM(value)
FROM T
```

Or you can try to use CTE RECURSIVE to get which root node you want to `SUM`

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS(
 SELECT ID,value,parent_id
 FROM T 
 WHERE value IS NOT NULL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT t1.id,coalesce(t1.value,0) + c.value,t1.parent_id
 FROM CTE c 
 INNER JOIN T t1 ON c.parent_id = t1.id
) 
SELECT id,SUM(value),parent_id
FROM CTE
GROUP BY id,parent_id
order by id
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=465c247016897468126e1a05e6bd8cb2)

Answer (score 0):

**update 24-04-2022**

Solution with [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE),  [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) and [ANY()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16)

```
WITH RECURSIVE r as (
SELECT id
     , name
     , ARRAY[id] as path
     , coalesce(value,0) as value 
  FROM t1
 WHERE name = 'root'
 UNION ALL
SELECT t1.id
     , t1.name
     , array_append(r.path, t1.id) as path
     , r.value + coalesce(t1.value,0) as value
  FROM t1 
 INNER
  JOIN r
    ON t1.parent_id = r.id
)
SELECT id
     , name
     , (select sum(sq.value) from r sq where r.id = any(sq.path) ) as value
  FROM r
```

[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mY4cVMMaiFKoeHSGFCZFgV/2)

Comment: that didnt work for me as it's returning the list of nodes without aggregating the sum

Comment: basically what i want is the tree to have all of its parent nodes ( not just the root node ) contain the sum of their respective children as their value. what your code does is calculate the sum of the entire tree but the values of the parent nodes (A and B) still contain null

Comment: ok, try new query - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mY4cVMMaiFKoeHSGFCZFgV/2